# PHP extracting text from a URL

Tags: php, regex, query-string

I have a URL which looks something like this...

http://www.mydomain.co.uk/this-is-the-text-i-would-like-please.php

I would like the strip out the text after the / but before the .php and would like to remove the -'s

So the result would be

this is the text i would like please

The idea is to then use this as a title tag

I have tried substr, strrchr but just can't work out how to get exactly what I need.

Any help would be very much appreciated

Many thanks

Comment: please state all your requirements in the question rather than drip feeding them in comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do using `basename()`

```
$fname = basename('http://www.mydomain.co.uk/this-is-the-text-i-would-like-please.php');
$fname = str_replace('-', ' ', $fname);
```

### EDIT:

```
<?php
   $fname = basename('http://www.mydomain.co.uk/this-is-the-text-i-would-like-please.php');
   $fname = str_replace('-', ' ', $fname);
   $fname = substr($fname, 0, -4);
   echo $fname;
?>
```

### RESULT:

```
this is the text i would like please
```

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://ideone.com/TA8f6)**

Comment: This will keep the `.php` extension.

Comment: good question. I got same. The OP says 'perfect' on my post and it results in -1. Go figure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple string manipulation with [`strrpos()`](http://php.net/strrpos) and [`substr()`](http://php.net/substr), like this:

```
$str = 'http://www.mydomain.co.uk/this-is-the-text-i-would-like-please.php';
echo substr( $str, strrpos( $str, '/') + 1, -4);
```

This [will output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/YEAAuS):

```
this-is-the-text-i-would-like-please
```

Then, we replace the dashes with spaces, using [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/str_replace), like this:

```
$str = str_replace( '-', ' ', $str);
```

[To yield](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Vkf56p):

```
this is the text i would like please
```

The alternative is to use [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/parse_url), then replace the dashes, like so:

```
$str = parse_url( $str, PHP_URL_PATH);
$str = substr( $str, 1, -4); // strip off leading slash and .php from the end
$str = str_replace( '-', ' ', $str);
```

This will also yield the desired output.

**Finally,** the simplest way without string manipulation is using [`pathinfo()`](http://php.net/pathinfo), like so:

```
$str = 'http://www.mydomain.co.uk/this-is-the-text-i-would-like-please.php';
$str = pathinfo( $str, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
$str = str_replace( '-', ' ', $str);
```

Comment: Thanks Nick, used this in conjunction with sdjuan;s answer

Answer (score 0):

You can also use PHP's `$_SERVER` array.  The variable `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` will give you everything after the server name.  In this case, it would be "/this-is-the-text-i-would-like-please.php".

After that, you can just run whatever string functions strike your fancy. Here is an example using `explode()` and `substr`:

```
$noslash = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 1);  
/* $noslash = "this-is-the-text-i-would-like-please.php" (no leading slash)*/  

$parts = explode($noslash, ".");  
/*   
 * $parts[0] = "this-is-the-text-i-would-like-please"  
 * $parts[1] = "php"  
*/  
$title_tag = $parts[0];
```

Apologies for the formatting.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am not sure it would work in my case. I am using rewriterules in .htaccess. I think grabbing the URL in this way does not show my seo friendly URLS but rather the URL the rewrite is pointing to

Answer (score -1):

Like nickb but removing the - as well:

```
echo str_replace('-',' ',substr( $str, strrpos( $str, '/') + 1, -4));
```

which will output

```
this is the text i would like please
```

or if you don't want the %20 either it would be:

```
 echo str_replace('%20',' ',str_replace('-',' ',substr( $str, strrpos( $str, '/') + 1, -4)));
```

Comment: written based on nickb original answer,,,

Comment: Perfect, many thanks. Is it also possible to remove %20 as well as the -'s ?

Comment: sure, just leave out the space in the replace str_replace('-','',... although BTW that is not what you asked for orginally.

Comment: Sorry i still want the spaces as in my original question, but as well as replacing - with a space I was also wondering how to replace %20 with a space. So if I had this-is-the%20text It would show as this is the text. Thanks

Comment: You'd just do an extra replace on the string str_replace('%20',' ',...)